# How to create a new pom file with additional dependencies and add it during build time?

Tags: java, maven, formsflow.ai, formsflow

I am currently using formsflow.ai opensource version 4.0.5.
I want to include a new Listener to the bpm module which has a new library dependency which is not currently in the solution. Although, I managed to add the new library in main pom.xml, since the requirement is for one of my client I just cannot modify the root pom.xml file. Is their an option available in formsflow / maven to include profiles and choose pom?
If it already available in formsflow, then how can I configure the same?
Please give me a solution.

Comment: Create separate Maven module...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can checkout how to add profile on a pom.xml file from maven documentation [how to add profile in maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).
In formsflow.ai we let our users manage the additional library dependency using an extra pom.xml (pom-.xml).
You can always refer to our internal documentation and also provided with a pom-default.xml to start with.
The facts about these profiling are.

1. you can add as many as number of unique profiling in pom.xml by mapping the default configuration.
2. You can add only 1 module per profile, since the docker build look up for the pom in the base directory and adding more than one module will override target.
3. You need to change profile param in Dockerfile before building it if you want to go with a profile other than default.

Hope this helps

Comment: Adding a module in a profile is a bad idea because that will produce issues while doing a release of your project...

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the usage. if i have 5 customers and each customer have their on libraries then i can just create 5 different filles for them to maintain their changes. yeah also, github branching also required to not let code interfere each other